# Auto Width with Float right contents

Tags: html, css, css-float, width

I am trying to align a `span` to the right of an `a` element without pushing it onto another line and without manually setting the width of the containing `div`.

I have tried all sorts of combinations of `white-space`,`position`,`float`,`text-align` etc, but I simply cannot get this to work.

Here is an example of the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/QgzbY/2/

Notice the 'Ctrl+Shift+S' is on the line below 'Save Document As', I want this to be on the same line, aligned to the right like the line above. In other words, it needs to increase the width on the containing element in order to fit the shortcut text.

**Question in short:** How can I float an element to the right of a parent element, whilst always keeping the contents on one line?

***If this cannot be achieved using CSS, then please don't waste your time helping me with the  Javascript as there are many more people on the Stack that need help and I can write this part myself. I was just hoping it wouldn't be necessary :-)***

Comment: +1, for the way question has been phrased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all of your answers. Unfortunately, it seems that what I was trying to achieve is not possible without manipulating the widths of the menus. I thought this might be the case :-(

Thanks anyway for all your tips

Answer (score 1):

I've added a `<p>` tag around the "Save Document As" text, and then an ID to certain elements so you know what I am changing/affecting. I only fixed the one line, so you can see what I changed and then fix it for the rest as well.

Basically, you want to remove the float on `.shortcut`, and display block/float left the img and span inside the `<a>`. I did this with ID's rather than complex selectors so you can see what I'm doing.

```
.shortcut {
    float: none !important; // over riding your declaration elsewhere
}

#lol, #lolimg {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QgzbY/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however it seems that @defau1t's answer works better

Comment: @BenCarey Oh I see, I didn't know the menu was to have a fixed width

Comment: You are right! I have just gone through the answer and noticed. Looks like yours is the better answer

Comment: @BenCarey Oops sorry deleted thinking you didn't want it haha. Yeah this should take into account the width of "Save Document As"

Comment: I wouldn't have thought this would work! Very weird, thanks for your help :-)

Comment: I have just realised that this does not solve the question completely as the text in the 'shortcut' is not aligned to the right of the menu!. This is why I was having such trouble with it! :-(

Comment: @BenCarey Add `text-align: right;` to the container (`.key-ctrl-s`): http://jsfiddle.net/QgzbY/5/

Comment: The Ctrl+S and Ctrl+Shift+S are not aligned together though :-(

Comment: @BenCarey Indeed, don't really know what to suggest for that

Comment: Exactly, I didn't think this was possible :-(

Comment: @BenCarey Infact I do know what I would suggest, but it involves tables and I'm sure it wouldn't be favoured :P

Comment: Absolutely, I agree, don't want to touch tables, however easy it would make this! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this is this one you need?

```
<li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="key-ctrl-s">
       <img src="//beta.example.net/_images/_icons/save-20x20.png"/>
       <span class="text-hint">Save Document</span>
       <span class="shortcut">Ctrl+S</span></a>
    </li>
```

css

```
.text-hint{display: inline; float: left;}
.shortcut{display:inline;float:right;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LFkkL/

Comment: please look the jsfiddle example

Comment: Afraid not, you have increased the `min-width`. This does solve the automatic width issue.

Answer (score 0):

I leveraged the position attributes to achieve something worth looking at. Giving the parent a relative position and its child the absolute posiiton, and then used right values to set it at proper position.

further I also increased the width in the below line

```
.win_menu li {
    display:block !important;
    float:none !important;
    padding:0 !important;
    margin:0 !important;
    height:20px !important;
    min-width:200px !important;
    white-space:nowrap !important;
    border:1px solid transparent !important;
    z-index:10 !important;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/N3MrD/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This doesn't quite work how I wanted it to as the width is not automatic. If the text 'Save Document As' is longer then it will overlap the shortcut :-(